# Content-type projects in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Before upgrading to VS2013, I was able to open Content-only type projects in VS2012.  I believe I needed to install Windows Phone SDK in order to have VS2012 support this type of a project.

After the upgrade, VS2013 is no longer able to open the project.  Is there anyway for me to have VS2013 recognize the project type?

Alternatively, is there a different way to maintain a number of non-compiling assets in a VS2013 project? (These assets could be .PHP/.CSS/.CS/.XML/.HTML/.DLL and other files)